# Error creating a table from a parquet in DuckDB

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, parquet, duckdb

I am trying to load a very big parquet as a table using DuckDB in python, in a jupyter notebook. I am using the following code:

```
authorDf = conn.execute("""
CREATE TABLE author AS SELECT * FROM read_parquet('/home/data/author.parquet');
""")
```

Following the DuckDB documentation it should work. However, when I run it crashes my session and I get the following error message:

> Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
> The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info.

Does anybody know why this might be happening and/or how to solve it?

Comment: For posterity, It was an issue with jupyter. I tried to run the same code in a simple python file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/3969
There exist two potential solutions.

you can try

1. setting an even lower memory limit explicitly

```
conn.execute(" SET memory_limit='8GB' ")
```

2. splitting up the file load into multiple calls

```
conn.sql("""

INSERT INTO author 
SELECT * FROM '/home/data/author.parquet' 
LIMIT ... 
OFFSET ...

""")
```